# Proving the uniquness of a functor

Tags: category-theory

The theme of this question, as the title suggests, is about how one goes about proving the uniqueness of a functor.

The specific motivation for my question is example 1.2.25 part(c) in Leinsters 'Basic Category Theory'.

(1)
Firstly we have that when we have a functor $F:  \mathfrak{A} \times \mathfrak{B} \rightarrow \mathfrak{C}$ there is a functor $F^{A} :\mathfrak{B} \rightarrow \mathfrak{C}$ defined such that for objects $B\in\mathfrak{B}$,

$F^A(B)=F(A,B)$ whre $A\in\mathfrak{A}$

and on maps $g$ in $\mathfrak{B}$ by

$F^A(g)=F(1_A,g)$.

There is also the extremely similarly defined functor $F_B:\mathfrak{A}\rightarrow\mathfrak{C}$    (It works how you would imagine).

(2)
Secondly we also have a family of functors $(F^A)_{A \in \mathfrak{A}}$ and $(F_B)_{B \in \mathfrak{B}}$

satisfying $F^A(B)=F_B(A)$ for $A \in \mathfrak{A}$ and $B \in \mathfrak{B}$

and

if $f:A \rightarrow B$ in $\mathfrak{A}$ and $g:B\rightarrow B'$ in $\mathfrak{B}$ then $F_{B'}(f)\circ F^A(g)=F^{A'}(g)\circ F_B(f)$.

The problem then is

Taking categories $\mathfrak{A}$ ,$\mathfrak{B}$ and $\mathfrak{C}$  and the family of functors mentioned above in (2), prove there is a unique functor $F:  \mathfrak{A} \times \mathfrak{B} \rightarrow \mathfrak{C}$ which satisfies the equations mentioned in (1).

My previous experience of proving uniqueness is limited to using inverses to show this and that (vectors and groups etc), this isn't really applicable here so any advice would be appreciated. Ideally I'd like to see the rigorous proof so I can note it down as a model for similar such problems I encounter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a deep look at what the problem is asking for:
you are looking for a functor $F \colon \mathfrak{A}\times\mathfrak{B} \to \mathfrak{C}$ such that for each $A \in \mathfrak{A}$ you have $F^A=F(A,-)$ and for every $B \in \mathfrak{B}$ you have $F_B=F(-,B)$.

These data basically are constraints on the functor indeed they tell you that the $F$ you are looking for should satisfy
$$F(A,B)=F^A(B)$$
or equivalently (by hypothesis)
$$F(A,B)=F_B(A)$$
for every pair $A \in \mathfrak{A}$ and $B \in \mathfrak{B}$,
and similarily that
$$F(f,g) = F^{A'}(g)\circ F_B (f)$$
or equivalently (again by the hypothesis)
$$F(f,g) = F_{B'}(f) \circ F^A(g)$$
for every $f \in \mathfrak{A}[A,A']$ and $g \in \mathfrak{B}[B,B']$.

So the constraints given by the problem turn out to be equations that define the objects and arrow part of the functor: they tell you what should be the value of the functor on both objects and arrow.
Since there cannot be two functors mapping in the same way objects and arrow this gives you the uniqueness.

To be fair it also gives to you *the unique functor*, the only thing that remains to be proven is that these data really define a functor: for now we simply have and object-function and an arrow-functions, one has to prove that sources, targets, compositions and identities are preserved, but that's just a matter of trivial calculations.

Hope thie helps.